# add class to last 2 links from a generate ul list

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a function that generates a unordered list of links and I want to use javascript to select the last 2 links so that I can align them to the right.

so in the following example I would need to select the **li parent** of link4 and link5, then add a class so i can style it

```
<ul>
<li>link1</li>
<li>link2</li>
<li>link3</li>
<li>link4</li>
<li>link5</li>
</ul>
```

In the end it should be something like this:

```
<ul>
<li>link1</li>
<li>link2</li>
<li>link3</li>
<li class="align_right">link4</li>
<li class="align_right">link5</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Couldn't you generate class="align_right" for the last 2 links when you build the list?

By the way, if you want to do this by javascript, you could do:

```
//get the sidebarmenu element
var sidebar = document.getElementById('sidebarmenu');

//getting the ul inside the wrapper
var ul = sidebar.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0];

//getting al the li childs
var li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
var totLi = li.length;

if(totLi >= 2){ //setting class to last 2
    li[totLi-1].className = "align_right";
    li[totLi-2].className = "align_right";
}
```

Edit: updated for your particular needs

Running example:
http://www.jsfiddle.net/steweb/m4v2J/

Comment: the website is actually a global cms system used by different clients, I can't just change the core files. I need to create a custom view script but I haven't figured that out yet, that's why I ask if there is not just a quick easy fix for javascript to use for now.

Comment: @steweb I can't get the ul by id but unfortunatly it's not the only ul on the page. It has a class of navigation and is wrapped in a div with an id sidebarmenu. I saw that you changed the code, could you add some comments to explian? thanks

Comment: @steweb awesome thank you very much it works perfectly, but can I ask one small modification? the 3 last links in the submenu is "links", "foto's" and "video's" (between <a></a>) is it possible to check for those specific links and eventually give that a class?

Comment: @krike You're welcome! Wait: Do you want to check if a link contains a particular text? Or you just want to check if a particular <li> has an <a> child and if so, you have to give to <li> that class..? Fork my example, complete the markup and explain me what you want to obtain ;)

Comment: @steweb I want to check if a link has a particular text and then add that link a class, but this modification is not urgent

Comment: @steweb perfect thank you very much :D, will that link remain for a few days or is going to be removed? (I'm talking about the link to the script)

Answer (score 2):

In Jquery:

```
$('ul li:last-child').prev('li').andSelf().addClass("align_right");
```

Comment: thank you for the anwser, but unfortunatly jQuery is not an option here.

Answer (score 1):

This best be done in the function generating those items, if you insist on client side script afterwards, here it is:

```
var oList = document.getElementById("myList");
var arrItems = oList.getElementsByTagName("li");
if (arrItems.length >= 2) {
    arrItems[arrItems.length - 2].className = "align_right";
    arrItems[arrItems.length - 1].className = "align_right";
}
```

For this to work, add ID to the `<ul>` tag and use it,